# To add data source in SSRS 2019 and prompt saying "Something went wrong, please try later"

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

On my machine I installed SSRS 2019 and connecting with the remote DB Server (SQL Database engine 2019) and connection is OK.

While creating a data source in web portal (http://SERVERNAME/ReportServer/) I am receiving the following error:

> ```
> Something went wrong, please try later
> ```

When I open the web service URL (http://SERVERNAME/Reports/) I am receiving an:

> ```
> HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`.
> ```

Is there any configuration I need to setup in web config or rsreport server file?

Error in Log:

> 2021-07-05 18:09:21.8279|ERROR|8|OData exception occurred: Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010+MissingEndpointException: The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'.The request failed with an empty response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057686/client-found-response-content-type-of-but-expected-text-xml-the-request-fail

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242788/ssrs-2017-client-found-response-content-type-of-but-expected-text-xml